# Angular2 init abstract class with object literal

Tags: angular, typescript

```
export abstract class GridColumn {
    public field?: string;
    public sortField?: string;
    public header?: string;
    public footer?: string;
    public sortable?: any = true;
    public editable?: boolean = false;
    public filter?: boolean = true;
    public filterMatchMode?: string = 'contains';
    public filterPlaceholder?: string;
    public style?: any;
    public styleClass?: string;
    public hidden?: boolean = false;
    public selectionMode?: string = 'multiple';
    public frozen?: boolean;
}
```

For example doing this only returns a object with those defined properties.

```
private gridConf: GridColumn = <GridColumn>{
    field: "test2",
    header: "Test2",
    filter: true,
    filterMatchMode: "contains",
    filterPlaceholder: "Search from Test",
    sortable: true,
    selectionMode: "single"
};
```

What i want is a object of type `GridColumn` That has all the defined properties and all the default values.
This does not work:

```
private gridConf: GridColumn = GridColumn({
    field: "test2",
    header: "Test2",
    filter: true,
    filterMatchMode: "contains",
    filterPlaceholder: "Search from Test",
    sortable: true,
    selectionMode: "single"
});
```

Constructor would force me to write a long one and i would always have to add all properties in a specific order.

The end goal would be to use something like this that has all default and/or defined properties in any order:

```
private columns: Array<GridColumn> = [
    <GridColumn>{
        field: "test",
        selectionMode: "single",
        filter: true,
        filterMatchMode: "contains",
        filterPlaceholder: "Search from Test",
        sortable: true,
        header: "Test"

    },
    <GridColumn>{
        field: "test2",
        header: "Test2",
        filter: true,
        filterMatchMode: "contains",
        filterPlaceholder: "Search from Test",
        sortable: true,
        selectionMode: "single"
    }
];
```

Closest "hack" i could find was to remove abstract and add, where fields refers to itself:

```
public constructor(
    fields?: GridColumn) {
    if (fields) Object.assign(this, fields);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible, but you could find a hacky way around it I suppose. Not saying this is best practice, but if you really really want it, this is how you can do it. FYI, default values are only initialised if you use `new GridColumn()` on a non abstract class:

**GridColumn**

```
export class GridColumn implements IGridColumn {

    public sortable: boolean = true;
    public editable: boolean = false;
    public filter: boolean = true;
    public filterMatchMode: string = 'contains';
    public hidden: boolean = false;
    public selectionMode: string = 'multiple';

    public field: string;
    public sortField: string;
    public header: string;
    public footer: string;
    public filterPlaceholder: string;
    public style: any;
    public styleClass: string;
    public frozen: boolean;

    constructor(data: IGridColumn = {}){
       Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

**IGridColumn**

```
export interface IGridColumn {
    public field?: string;
    public sortField?: string;
    public header?: string;
    public footer?: string;
    public sortable?: boolean;
    public editable?: boolean;
    public filter?: boolean;
    public filterMatchMode?: string;
    public filterPlaceholder?: string;
    public style?: any;
    public styleClass?: string;
    public hidden?: boolean;
    public selectionMode?: string;
    public frozen?: boolean;
}
```

**Usage**

```
private columns: Array<GridColumn> = [
    new GridColumn(<IGridColumn>{
        field: "test",
        selectionMode: "single",
        filter: true,
        filterMatchMode: "contains",
        filterPlaceholder: "Search from Test",
        sortable: true,
        header: "Test"

    }),
    new GridColumn(<IGridColumn>{
        field: "test2",
        header: "Test2",
        filter: true,
        filterMatchMode: "contains",
        filterPlaceholder: "Search from Test",
        sortable: true,
        selectionMode: "single"
    })
];
```

Let me again stress that I believe that this is not best practice. Even naming an interface starting with an I is frowned upon :D